# Calling a lambda function later with different objects/arguments

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming

I am a newbie in java functional interfaces so I want to see if this is possible and if not please explain me why not and what is possible in order to achieve my idea

I have these classes

```
public class A {
...
public String getInfo();
...
}

public class B {
...
public String getOtherInfo();
...
}
```

I want to pass the references to these functions to another object like this:

```
obj.init(A::getInfo)
obj.init(B::getOtherInfo)
```

so that later I can use/call these functions on different objects of type A or B inside the build functions:

```
obj.build(a1);
obj.build(a2);
...
obj.build(b1);
obj.build(b2);
```

PS1 I cannot use regular interfaces for this cause there are lot of getters and lots of classes similar to A which I want to use for this procedure and they are not related with one another

PS2 I try to avoid reflection cause you cannot trace the function calls

PS3 my example is not exactly working as is it throws this error: "non static method cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: If those classes like `A` are not related, you anyway cannot derive a method reference resolving to their implementations of `get()`. The simplest is to make them implement a common interface (the closest being `Supplier<String>`)

Comment: I get "non static function cannot be referenced from a static context" when I do that. I want to be able to store the function call/name somehow and later apply it for lots of  objects of type A

Comment: Well, you have to sort that out before even asking the question in your post. Without the context and code leading to it, we have no idea what you're doing wrong (beside guesses)

Comment: this was the context but there is no code so far, this is what I am trying to do but I I dont know how and I expect an idea from you if its even possible

Answer (score 0):

A::get is a [Java Method Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). You should be able to store it for use later. As it's an instance method you'll need the instance object as well. So something like this might work:

```
Function<A,String> getFunction = A::get;
```

And whenever you need to use it you can do

```
//assuming you have an object instance of A which is a
getFunction.apply(a)
```

You can also pass it to other methods by declaring the method to take a functional parameter like this:

```
public void someOtherMethod(Function<A,String> param) {
     //do whatever with param.
     //invoke this with an instance of A when you're ready
     param.apply(a);
}
```

Here's a reference that might help: https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-double-colon-operator

Comment: I want to be able to use case: "An Instance Method of an Arbitrary Object of a Particular Type" but for some reason i get that error

Answer (score 0):

Made 2 mistakes

1. should have used Function<T, R> instead of Supplier
2. the error is thrown even if there is a slight mismatch of parameters even on the generic types. So an example of my function which accepts the Function parameter should be declared like this:

```
public <T extends Base> init (Function <T, String> f){
  this.f = f;
}
```

and later I do something like:

```
public String build (A a){
  return this.f.apply(a);
}
```

(so I had to make A, B implement some useless interface)